# how do i add miliseconds option in this code?

Tags: android

I am learning android. I made this stopwatch app work from my reference book.It only shows Hour:minutes:seconds but I want to add milliseconds right to the seconds.how do I do that.

code::-

```
public class StopWatchActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

int seconds;
boolean running;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_stop_watch);
    runTimer();
}

public void startTimer(View view){
    running = true;
}

public void stopTimer(View view){
        running = false;
    }

public void resetTimer(View view){
        running = true;
        seconds = 0;
    }

public void runTimer(){
    final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer);
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
                int hours = seconds / 3600;
                int minutes = (seconds % 3600) / 60;
                int sec = seconds % 60;
                String time = String.format("%d:%02d:%02d", hours, 
minutes,sec);
                textView.setText(time);
            if(running) {
                seconds++;
            }
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    });

}
}
```

Comment: So what is the problem for you to add miliseconds? You should not ask us for complete code, only to help you to make it.

Answer (score 1):

The first step would be to change the field `seconds` to `milliSeconds` because you want to keep track of that TimeUnit.

When restarting your handler with `handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);` define 1 millisecond as delay instead of 1000 (= 1 Second) like this `handler.postDelayed(this, 1);` then you just need to adjust your calculations and you are done :-)

Answer (score 0):

An easier solution would be:
Instead of saving the *elapsed seconds* in your activity, save the *time* that the timer started (e.g. `startTime`)

Then, in your handler's runnable, get the current time and subtract the start time to find the elapsed time.

Pseudocode:

```
long startTimeNanos

public void runTimer() {

    startTime = new Date()
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            long currentTime = System.nanoTime()
            long elapsedNanos = currentTime - startTimeNanos

            // calculate seconds and millis
            // and set the textview text

            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    });
}
```

This way, you can change the time that the handler fires and it won't affect anything else.